# SQLite with actual queries in Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I am porting over some code from an older mobile application and I was hoping to use SQLite.
All the tutorials I could find say to use the sql-net-pcl package.
When I do that, I find I cannot really use simple queries and it seems like I must use the ORM.
This will vastly increase the amount of work I will have to do because now I cannot directly port the SQL statements.

The following code throws no exception:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Table aaaaaa
try
{
    string sql2 =
        "XCREATE TABLE aaaaaa ( \n" +
        "    sync_seq INTEGERXXXXX NOT NULL \n" +
        ") \n";
    con.Execute(sql2, new object[0]);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    DisplayAlert("Error!", $"{ex.Message}", "OK");
    return;
}
```

And neither does this:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Table allowMO
sql =
    "CREATE TABLE allowMO ( \n" +
    "    flag TEXTXXXX NOT NULL, \n" +
    "    cap  REAL NOT NULL \n" +
    ") \n";
cmd.CommandText = sql;
_ = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I tried to use the System.Data.SQLite package that I use on the desktop but I get an error about a missing interop file when I create a connection.

"SQLite.Interop.dll assembly: type: member:(null)"

Has anyone used a package that allows for plain old SQL queries?

Comment: I tried using Microsoft.Data.SQLite but it does not seem stable. I can't delete or even see the database file, it's like it's being buffered somewhere. Also, it sometimes just flakes out and never even throws an exception. Is the ORM stuff solid in sqlite-net-pcl? Would it be worth the time to change my code? It's like starting from scratch almost.

Comment: You could check the link below about how to use the ORM with sqlite. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows

Comment: Well, I rebooted my machine and got the first query to throw an error.
It turns out I did not fully understand how SQLite data types worked and the second query is perfectly acceptable. Data Types are basically a free for all and TEXTXXXX just means 'whatever you want to shove in there'.

Comment: Wendy Zang - Thank you for the link. I am using the pattern shown there in my re-write.